# Format a decimal to a minor currency

Tags: c#

I need to format a decimal to a minor currency e.g. 10.00 should be 1000.

```
decimal currency = 10.00m;
System.Console.WriteLine(currency.ToString("######"));
```

Produces 10, how do I get the decimal points to be added to that?

Comment: how about `* 100`?

Comment: Nice one it is getting late here I should have though of that

Comment: Can you put that as the answer so I can mark it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is as simple as just

```
* 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create an extension method like this that would produce always the expected result, with the required number of decimals:

```
public static class DecimalExtension
{
    public static string FormatAsMinorCurrency(this decimal value) {
        var numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
        numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
        numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
        numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "";
        return value.ToString("c", numberFormat).Replace(".", "");
    }
}
```

The results:

```
1.FormatAsMinorCurrency() 
100

10.FormatAsMinorCurrency()
1000

1000000.34102350915091M.FormatAsMinorCurrency()
100000034
```